# Processing (receiving) external payments -- how to tell Magento that payment was received

Tags: magento, payment

I have a number of check or money order payments that I received through snail mail, and I have noticed recently that even though I have shipped these orders and they show as "complete" in the backend, The dashboard stats do not reflect that these payments were logged.

I can't find a way to manually tell Magento that payment was received in the backend using any arbitrary non-automatic payment method (be it check, money order, cash, paypal outside of the automated method, etc), so I usually just make a comment and then "ship", but I would like for the stats to update (lifetime sales, last amounts graph).

I have googled without success, just keep getting the same "how to accept checks" wiki articles.  Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's related to Magento, v1.9 (which is about end of life'd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I figured it out.  You simply have to create the invoice.